# Determine function name in AS2 and AS3

Tags: actionscript-3

Is there a way, in both Actionscript 2 and 3 to determine the name of a function from the Function object. So for example I want something like:

```
function Log(message:String, fn:Function):void
{
    textbox.text = message + " function name: " + fn.determineName(); 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at these questions, the answers might satisfy your needs:

[can an actionscript function find out its own name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/711404/can-an-actionscript-function-find-out-its-own-name)
[in flex, get function name from Function object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1230028/in-flex-get-function-name-from-function-object)
[Actionscript 3 introspection -- function names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1208418/actionscript-3-instrospection-function-names)